# Alternative to array_shift function

Tags: php, arrays, split

Ok, I need keys to be preserved within this array and I just want to shift the 1st element from this array.  Actually I know that the first key of this array will always be 1 when I do this:

```
// Sort it by 1st group and 1st layout.
ksort($disabled_sections);
    foreach($disabled_sections as &$grouplayout)
        ksort($grouplayout);
```

Basically I'd rather not have to ksort it in order to grab this array where the key = 1.  And, honestly, I'm not a big fan of array_shift, it just takes to long IMO.  Is there another way.  Perhaps a way to extract the entire array where $disabled_sections[1] is found without having to do a foreach and sorting it, and array_shift.  I just wanna add $disabled[1] to a different array and remove it from this array altogether.  While keeping both arrays keys structured the way they are.  Technically, it would even be fine to do this:

```
$array = array();
$array = $disabled_sections[1];
```

But it needs to remove it from $disabled_sections.  Can I use something like this approach...

```
$array = array();
$array = $disabled_sections[1];
$disabled_sections -= $disabled_sections[1];
```

Is something like the above even possible??

Thanks.

Comment: what is the size of this array? overall items number?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68947156/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no `-=` operator in that fashion, you can use unset to remove that element from an array:

```
unset(disabled_sections[1]);
```

But that's just implementing your own version of shift. I do wonder under what situation you're finding `array_shift()` to be 'slow' and how  you're testing said slowness.

Numeric arrays are sorted numerical by default - no ksort is required. Maybe you should try something like

```
while($array = array_shift($group_of_arrays)) {

  // ... do stuff
}
```

If you are not concerned about the order in which you pull elements out of the array, you can use "array_pop" instead of "array_shift".  Since "array_pop" takes the elements off of the end of the array, no reindexing is required and performance increases dramatically.  In testing with an array of about 80,000 entries I am seeing about a 90% decrease in processing time with "array_pop".

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of that...lol.  I was reading comments on array_shift located here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php, and a lot of people are saying it's too slow there.  I don't want it to be slow on my end either.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Ok, I don't think `array_unshift` would help me here.  I'm talking about `array_shift`, not `array_unshift`.

Comment: `array_unshift` was a typo :)  array_shift is only 'slow' against VERY large arrays, which is why I asked under what situation you were using it .. ie. an array with 500 items, or an array with 500,000 items.

Comment: furthermore, the numbers are coming from the database, where the first key is an id value from a column in the database.  Cheers, you reminded me of the `unset()`.  I feel totally dumb now... hehe ;)

Comment: The array can have a million items really.  Well, maybe that's an exaggeration.  But there's really no limit to the array as it grabs all rows from a table... so it's needed to be fast, not slow.  Thanks, unset should do the trick than :)

Answer (score 6):

Despite there being an accepted answer to this; in case someone else stumbles across this, a way to unset the first element of an array (*regardless of its key, or the order of its keys*) without using `array_shift` is:

```
reset($array); // sets internal array pointer to start
unset($array[key($array)]); // key() returns key of current array element
```

Though I'm *fairly* convinced that's what `array_shift` does internally (so I imagine there would be no performance gain to this), excepting an additional return of the value retrieved:

```
$element = reset($array); // also returns element
unset($array[key($array)]);
return $element;
```

Just for completion's sake.

Comment: That's not *quite* what what array_shift does, shift does all those things PLUS renumbers the entire array in the case of a numeric array - which is why it can be slow on large arrays.

Comment: I tend to work with associate arrays as exclusively as possible, so I had no idea. :3 Good to know!