# array_shift but preserve keys

Tags: php, arrays

My array looks like this:

```
$arValues = array( 345 => "jhdrfr", 534 => "jhdrffr", 673 => "jhrffr", 234 => "jfrhfr" );
```

How can I remove the first element of an array, but preserve the numeric keys? Since `array_shift` changes my integer key values to `0, 1, 2, ...`.

I tried using `unset( $arValues[ $first ] ); reset( $arValues );` to continue using the second element (now first), but it returns `false`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
reset( $a );
unset( $a[ key($a)]);
```

A bit more useful version:

```
// rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element
// and returns the value of the first array element. 
$value = reset( $a );

// returns the index element of the current array position
$key   = key( $a );

unset( $a[ $key ]);
```

Functions:

```
// returns value
function array_shift_assoc( &$arr ){
  $val = reset( $arr );
  unset( $arr[ key( $arr ) ] );
  return $val; 
}

// returns [ key, value ]
function array_shift_assoc_kv( &$arr ){
  $val = reset( $arr );
  $key = key( $arr );
  $ret = array( $key => $val );
  unset( $arr[ $key ] );
  return $ret; 
}
```

Comment: Because we specifically want to deal with the first element. `reset()` moves the array ponter to the first element, `key()` returns the index of that element.

Comment: After using that, I call `current( $a );` which returns false. Whats wrong?

Comment: I tried quickly googling that what will be the current element after unsetting, but found nothing. "If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, current() returns FALSE."

Comment: I made it by using another way: moving the index also into the value, so I use an array of key and value as element value and let PHP handle the keys 0, 1, 2... then using array_shift is OK since it will alter the keys. But there is still no solution for my question.

Comment: In this case I don't understand your question, maybe edit it or add some examples, etc.

Answer (score 15):

```
// 1 is the index of the first object to get
// NULL to get everything until the end
// true to preserve keys
$arValues = array_slice($arValues, 1, NULL, true);
```

Comment: The best answer here. Doesn't mess with pointers and is readable.

Comment: Definitely a readable answer. Unfortunately it's notably worse performance-wise which could make a difference on large arrays. I believe array_slice() is O(N) runtime and O(N) additional memory usage (at least until garbage collection frees the old copy of the array which is overwritten). The other solution using key() and unset() will be O(1) for both. Throw it in a function named "array_pop()" and you can get both performance and readability.

Answer (score 7):

When I need to do this I used:

```php
unset($a[array_key_first($a)]);
```

`array_key_first()` was introduced/available towards the end of 2018 in PHP 7.3. I did not need to deal with pointers for my use case, however you can still run `reset($a)` when needed. I didn't see any recent answers, so I'd though I'd add this in.

Comment: Good job filling this gap with current/modern functionality.  I wish more people would make worthwhile necroposts like this.  I also like that your answer is receiving uv's -- this is a rare indication that SO can "work properly".

Comment: Polyfill at the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php#refsect1-function.array-key-first-notes

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_shift_associative(&$arr){
    reset($arr);
    $return = array(key($arr)=>current($arr));
    unset($arr[key($arr)]);
    return $return; 
}
```

this function uses biziclop's method but returns a `key=>value` pair.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me...

```
$array = array('1','2','3','4');

reset($array);
$key = key($array);
$value = $array[$key];
unset($array[$key]);

var_dump($key, $value, $array, current($array));
```

Output:

```
int(0) 
string(1) "1" 
array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" }
string(1) "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to @PhilF's but is compatible with older versions of PHP - for that rare instance when you need to write code which is compatible with a PHP version older than **PHP 7.3**.

If `$myArray` looks like this:

```
[
  345 => "jhdrfr",
  534 => "jhdrffr",
  673 => "jhrffr",
  234 => "jfrhfr"
]
```

Then `array_keys($myArray)` will look like this:

```
[
  345,
  534,
  673,
  234
]
```

and `array_keys($myArray)[0]` will be:

```
345
```

Therefore:

```
unset($myArray[array_keys($myArray)[0]]);
```

will remove the first element, *without resetting keys*, giving the result:

```
[
  534 => "jhdrffr",
  673 => "jhrffr",
  234 => "jfrhfr"
]
```

Comment: This is the same approach as the accepted answer, but uses `array_keys($a)[0]` instead of a `reset($a); key($a);` pair. Since the question was asked in 2013, by definition most of the answers will work fine in PHP 5.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, @miken32. When I noticed that `array_shift()` was re-indexing the array in my script, I set about looking for a parameter to prevent this from happening. While searching the web, without reading it anywhere, the solution above occurred to me. After testing it successfully, I thought I would check Stack Overflow to see if this solution was already archived. It wasn't, so I've added it. My intention isn't to replace the accepted answer, but to add to the number of approaches which might be employed to solve this particular problem.

Comment: Good idea, but for large arrays it's inefficient: it has to build a new array with all the keys, then immediately dumps it. The docs has a nice polyfill: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php#refsect1-function.array-key-first-notes